# Use 3rd-Plugins in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to use 3rd javascript plugins in my application like Typed.js, AOS.js, mo.js or whatsoever. I still figuring out the proper way to use those 3rd plugins. Although some of them provide a great documentation, I still overwhelmed because there is just few which provide a complete example, I still newbie in Angular

I still figuring out where to put a javascript/jquery code properly in my *.component.ts file, how to import the plugin and all the things related to make the 3rd plugins work.

And also I still looking for the way to listen to the event like mouse scroll. I read about HostListener but there is no easy explanation, so I just use it without complete understanding.

Is there any thing I could read/learn to solve those problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can import the .js file using

1) import * as aos from './AOS.js';

2) create a definition file index.d.ts inside 'login' folder with methods and class.

```
export declare class AOS{
    type: any;
    method1(): string;
}
```

3) In your component, you can import as import { AOS } from './login';

```
AOS.method1();
```

Comment: Specifically for AOS you can install the types definition file by doing 'npm install @types/aos'